# C# Client/Server socket will not connect again after it has been disconnected

Tags: c#, sockets

I am building a server and client based application that communicates via sockets (typical stuff).

The intended functionality, is that the client connects, they send some data back and forth, and then the client closes the connection. Some time later, the client reconnects, they send some more information back and forth, and it disconnects again.

The first step in the process works fine. The client connects, BeginAccept fires off as desired, and they talk for a while. The connection appears to close just fine (Disconnect()), and the logic runs through and calls BeginAccept again. However, if the client attempts to connect again, AcceptCallback will not trigger.

Other questions/answers online suggest that the socket needs to be reinstated, but I do that here.

In the real version (trimmed for here) I have extensive exception handling and logging yet there are no exceptions or errors to work with.

If I restart the service, it all works again (but only once), which leads me to believe it is my server code and not my client.
It appears that the AsyncCallback is simply never triggered again.

**What am I doing wrong so that I cannot connect more than once?**
Thanks!

On the server, in a thread I have the following (this gets called at the start, as well as when the disconnect signal is sent from the client):

```
try
{
    //check connected, and if not connected, then close socket and reopen
    if (mDisconnectFlag == true)
    {
        mDisconnectFlag = false;
        this.Disconnect();
    }

    if (listener == null || listener.Connected == false)
    {
        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        this.listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        this.listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        this.listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        this.listener.Listen(10);
        // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
        this.listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
    }
    else if (listener.Connected == false || mAcceptCallBackFlag == true)
    {
        // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
        this.listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

    }
    // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
    _retevent = ProcessSocketEvent.WaitOne(mSocketProcessTimeInterval, false);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //logging - don't worry about this
}
```

The disconnection is as follows:

```
public void Disconnect()
{
    try
    {
        this.listener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        this.listener.Disconnect(false);
        this.listener.Dispose();
        listener = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //logging
    }

}
```

Finally, the call back:

```
public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
        this.listener = handler;

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();

        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        mAcceptCallBackFlag = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //logging
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you never call `BeginAccept()` again. Indeed, you discard the original listening socket as soon as you get your first connection.

There are lots of correct examples of how to write socket-based network code around, so I won't go into too much detail. Especially, since there's not a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here to work with. But, in the code you posted, the main change that appears to be needed is to replace:

```
   this.listener = handler;
```

with:

```
   this.listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
```

There's not enough context to know what the other code in your first snippet is doing, but it's likely you should also remove this:

```
else if (listener.Connected == false || mAcceptCallBackFlag == true)
{
    // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
    this.listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

}
```

And there's nothing that would set the `ProcessSocketEvent` that you wait on here:

```
_retevent = ProcessSocketEvent.WaitOne(mSocketProcessTimeInterval, false);
```

If that's not in the part of the code you've omitted, you should either get rid of the `WaitOne()` call, or make sure you've set the event handle. Again, it's not clear what the purpose of that code is. If you are in a loop where you expect to call `BeginAccept()` again, you've mixed your paradigms (an unfortunate consequence that occurs sometimes when people follow the MSDN socket example, which is terrible). If you want to block and accept in a loop, just use the synchronous `Accept()` method. If you want to use `BeginAccept()`, then you don't need a loop; just call `BeginAccept()` after you call `EndAccept()`, in the completion callback method.

If you need more help than that, please improve the question and make sure there's a good MCVE.

Comment: Thank you for the information about BeginAccept(). The first code snippet I gave was running in a loop. So I was calling BeginAccept() again. However, I applied your first suggestion and stopped the looping and it works.